# line chart using secondary y-axis with negative percentage value

Tags: javascript, charts, highcharts

I have two y-axis.
using primary y-axis I have created column chart but when I am trying to create line chart using secondary y-axis with negative percentage data values my line chart is going down from x-axis I don't want that so do anyone know about this please help me as soon as possible ?

```
 $(function () {
    $('#container').highcharts({

        colors: [ '#24CBE5','#FF9655'],

        chart: {
            type: 'column'
        },
        title: {
            text: 'combine chart'
        },
        plotOptions: {
            series: {
               pointPadding:0,
                groupPadding:0.3,
                borderWidth: 1,
                //shadow: false
            }
        },
        xAxis: {
           gridLineWidth: 0,
           minorGridLineWidth: 0,
            categories: ['Oct 15', 'Nov 15', 'Dec 15', 'Jan 15', 'Feb 15','March 15'],

        },
         yAxis: [{ // Primary yAxis
            min: 0,
            max: 4,
            gridLineWidth: 0,
                minorGridLineWidth: 0,
            labels: {
                formatter: function () {
                    return this.value + '$';
                }
            },
            title: {
                text: 'Million',
            }
        }, { // Secondary yAxis
                tickInterval:5, //set ticks to 20
                 min: -30,
                max: 10,
                column :{
                 stacking:'percent'
                },
                title: {
                    text: '% Percantage',
                },
                labels: {
                formatter: function () {
                    return this.value + '%';
                }
            },
                opposite: true
            }],
        series: [
        {
            type: 'column',
            name: 'AB',
            data: [3, 3.5, 3.3, 3.6, 2.5,2]
        }, {
            type: 'column',
            name: 'BC',
            data: [3.3, 2, 3.3, 3.4, 2.9,3]
        }, {
            // USE THIS CODE TO GENERATE LINE CHART (I HAVE USED ONLY MILION AND CREATED LINE CHART BUT INSTEAD I WANT TO USE percentage )
            type: 'line',
            name: '% Percantage',
            data: [0.5, 2, 0, 4, 3.7,2.6],
            color: '#000000',
            //border: 1,
            marker: {
                    fillColor: '#FFFFFF',
                    lineWidth: 2,
                    lineColor: null // inherit from series
                }
        }]
    });
});
```

Comment: Could you post how it should be printed? Because at this moment chart is displayed properly (according to define of your min/max on yAxis). Let me know if on left yAxis 0 should be aligned to 0 on right hand?

Comment: hi Sebastian , right now its  displayed properly because i haven't used negative values to create line chart .if u use negative values to create line chart it will go down .

Comment: use negative  percentage value for line chart

Comment: When you set negative value, series is below chart xAxis, because you set a min value on yAxis as 0. So this is still proper behaviour. http://jsfiddle.net/gfeye57n/ in case when you would like to print whole serie, remove min param from yAxis.

Comment: HI ,Sebastian Bochan  I have tried using   yAxis : 1 in the line and its working fine but i don't know it is the right solution, can you please help me on this  {
            type: 'line',
            yAxis : 1,
            name: '% Percantage',
            data: [0.5, 2, 0, -4, 3.7, 2.6],
            color: '#000000',
            //border: 1,
            marker: {
                fillColor: '#FFFFFF',
                lineWidth: 2,
                lineColor: null // inherit from series
            }
        }

Comment: I did that, so let me know what is wrong on this chart: http://jsfiddle.net/gfeye57n/1/

Comment: instead of giving yAxis to  type:column  i have tried giving yAxis:1  to  type: line (percentage) and its working fine but  set tickInterval  is not working as i want it.

Comment: Set a [alignTicks](http://api.highcharts.com/highcharts#chart.alignTicks) as false.

Comment: Thank you Sebastian Bochan you saved me

Comment: I added  my comment as an answer.

Answer (score 0):

You need to set [alignTicks](http://api.highcharts.com/highcharts#chart.alignTicks) as false.

```
chart:{
    alignTicks: false
}
```